# Box V2.0 API File Upload Not Uploading or returning error

Tags: file-upload, box-api

I have searched and not found anything that answers the issue I'm experiencing. If I have missed this, my apologies.

Using curl, I have been trying to upload a small image file to an existing Box folder, but with no success. It does not return an error message that I can debug with. The folder_id I use is valid and I can list it's contents using relevant API call.

Below is the verbose results of the POST request. I would appreciate it if someone could shed light on where I'm going wrong

```
curl -k -v https://www.box.com/api/2.0/files/content/ -H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN" -F filename="c:\alarms.gif" -F folder_id=FOLDER_ID

* About to connect() to www.box.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 74.112.184.70...
* connected
* Connected to www.box.com (74.112.184.70) port 443 (#0)
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using RC4-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: serialNumber=ts5jamwzcjWP0oTyh2m74yh0zsB2zyOR; C=US; ST=California; L=Palo    Alto; O=Box.net, Inc.; CN=*.box.com
*        start date: 2011-09
*        expire date: 2013-09
*        subjectAltName: www.box.com matched
*        issuer: C=US; O
*        SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> POST /api/2.0/files/content/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.28.0
> Host: www.box.com
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN
> Content-Length: 263
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------704f2d9b4096
>
* Done waiting for 100-continue
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Tue, 20 Nov 2012 08:14:13 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-control: private
< Content-Length: 30
<
{"total_count":0,"entries":[]}* Connection #0 to host www.box.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

The source file c:\alarms.gif is a valid file and exists. This is running from a windows host.

Any assistance or guidance will be appreciated

Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When uploading a local file using cURL, you need to prepend an `@` symbol to the file path; this tells cURL to upload the file at that path, as opposed to just reading the string.In your case you want:

```
curl -k -v https://www.box.com/api/2.0/files/content/ -H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN" -F filename=@"c:\alarms.gif" -F folder_id=FOLDER_ID
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly. Somehow missed that in the docs !